# python: editing specific lines in a text file.File not being read after first edit

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. Right now I'm trying to learn how to edit text files(overwrite them). 
So, I have a text file, which stores these ints just like that:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

then when I do this

```
with open('badgeNumbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    self.firstBadge = lines[0].strip()
    self.secondBadge = lines[1].strip()
    self.thirdBadge = lines[2].strip()
    self.fourthBadge = lines[3].strip()
    self.fifthBadge = lines[4].strip()
    int(self.thirdBadge)
    lines[2] = 56
    out = open('badgeNumbers.txt', 'w')
    out.writelines(str(lines))
    out.close()
```

it works and changes the number. 
in text file it is now saved like this:

```
['1\n', '2\n', 56, '3\n', '4\n', '5']
```

However, later if I want to run this again, it gives me this error:
self.secondBadge = lines[1].strip()
IndexError: list index out of range

I just need for it to be able to do the same thing as before the first text file edit. 
Can somebody please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that `56` does not have a new line at the end.  That means that it and the next line will be displayed on the same line.  The second problem is that you are writing the string representation of the list onto one line instead of writing each string in the list on separate lines.  Change `lines[2] = 56` to `lines[2] = "56\n"`, and change `out.writelines(str(lines))` to `out.writelines(lines)`